# run a file.gms from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to create a python script that runs a file gams (myfile.gms).
My file is in a folder `F:\Otim\correct`, so I was using a part of a code that I saw in this forum. I made:

```
  import subprocess
  subprocess.check_call(["F:\Otim\correct\myfile.gms"])
```

and I get an error:

```
Runtime error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 80, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 506, in check_call retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
 startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used gams but after a quick look at www.gams.com it sounds like myfile.gms is not the file to be executed but the input file to be given as argument to the gams executable.

So you should try something like :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call([r"C:\path\to\programs\GAMS.exe",r"F:\Otim\correct\myfile.gms"])
```

Notice : there is a GAMS python API which could give you a more portable solution.

Comment: I tryed this but I get an error again: 

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Did you replace C:\path\to\programs\GAMS.exe by the actual location of the GAMS executable on your computer ?

Comment: yes, I made: subprocess.check_call(["C:\GAMS\win64\24.4\gams.exe","F:\Otim\correct\myfile.gms"])

Comment: It gives this error:
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 81, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 506, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I've forgotten to tell you to work with raw strings, please try this :subprocess.check_call([r"C:\GAMS\win64\24.4\gams.exe",r"F:\Otim\correct\myfile.gms‌​"]). Notice the r before the adress.

Comment: Thnak's!! Now program opens the comand window, close and show this error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 81, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\GAMS\\win64\\24.4\\gams.exe', 'F:\\Otimizacao\\correto\\ElectGridsV03.gms']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: No, but look at the gams ouput files to see if gams is complaining about something wrong in the data or the command line options.

Comment: I already solved! If I change "\\GAMS\\win64\\24.4\\gams.exe" to \\GAMS\\win64\\24.4\\gamside.exe I solve the error.. I don't understand why, but I think it is a directory problem.. But now I already work with this! Thank's!!